# What query to append the 10 next posts?

Tags: wp-query

I am loading more posts with ajax when clicking on a button. There is 4 posts when you arrive on the page and everytime you click on the button, it needs to load 4 more. What query would I need to use?

On my ajax.php, this is what my custom query looks like:

```
$queryLoadPosts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'track',
        'posts_per_page' => 4
    ));
```

I also tried 'page_id' => 2, but it did not work. I also though about doing a loop and incrementing a variable and only start echoing the posts when ex: $i >3, but that would be the worst code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `$paged` param and pass it with the ajax call.

```
$queryLoadPosts = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'track',
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'paged' => (isset($_REQUEST['paged']) && intval($_REQUEST['paged'])) ? $_REQUEST['paged'] : 1
));
```

First time you click the button the `paged` param must be 2, second time 3, and so on... so you need to store somewhere the last value of paged with js, use a `data-` attribute of the button can be a good idea.

see [Pagination Parameters of WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) on Codex